# How to get top most view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Is there way i can get the top most or current view in swiftUI while coming from background in delegate?

`func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene){}`

Comment: What are you going to do with it? I almost sure you should not do it via view, because most you will have is *a copy* of content view.

Comment: Have some business logic which has UIViewController that need to shown on screen after coming from any screen. once its done then it will land into swiftUI top view

Comment: @Rocker did you get the answer?